# get the content of all span's with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the problem that I'm trying to get the content of all span's with the same class.

Thats the relevant html:

```
    @foreach($products as $product
        <div class="media-body">
             <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $product->title }}</h4>
             <p>{{ $product->short_description }}</p>
             <div class="pull-right">
                  <span class="priceCell">{{$product->sales_price}}</span>€
                  <span>Quantities: </span><span class="quantitie">{{ $product->quantity }}      </span>
                  <br>
             </div>
         </div>
    @endforeach
```

The $products variable have 6 different products. So 6 different quantities.
I need the different quantities as a array that looks like this:

var quantities = [25,20,15,10,5,1];

current js:

```
var quantities = document.getElementsByClassName("quantities");
alert(quantities) -- gives : html collection
```

I need the quantities array like this : `[10,5,3,1]`

Cause I want to use it with this code:

```
for (var q = 0; q < quantitys.length; q++) {
    endPrice += (parseInt(quantities[q]) * parseFloat(prices[q]));
}
```

prices variable also looks like this: [15.00, 20.00, ...]

and other things.. but nothing have worked for me. Can someone help me there? Thanks!

Comment: I also tried that but that returns only : undifined

Comment: Can you show the code - in your question - that you say returns `undefined`? If the existing answers *don't* answer your question (assuming you've interpreted and used the answer to that other question correctly) then we, or I, can reopen this question for you. Incidentally what's the resulting HTML that's generated by that script/templating language? Could you [edit] your question to include that also?

Answer (score 1):

Try use simple things

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("quantities");

for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
{
  alert(spans[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<span class="quantities">A</span>
<span class="quantities">B</span>
<span class="quantities">C</span>
<span class="quantities">D</span>
<span class="quantities">E</span>
```

Simple example with array

```js
function getSpanDataByClass(className){
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName(className),
      result = [];
  
  if(!spans){
    //no data 
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
    result.push(spans[i].innerHTML);
  }

  return result;
};

function runDebug(){
  var spanInnerData = getSpanDataByClass("quantities");
  
  alert(spanInnerData);
};

runDebug();
```

```html
<span class="quantities">A</span>
<span class="other">B</span>
<span class="quantities">C</span>
<span class="other">X</span>
<span class="quantities">Y</span>
<span class="quantities">Z</span>
```

Comment: well this doesn't work for me if I output the spans variable outside of my foreach. I'm getting the message : [object HTMLCollection] - its important to get them like : 15,10,5,1

Comment: @WellNo not sure that I get it. so u got some page with lots of `<span>` tags of `quantities` class, right?
first you select all, then jsut go throught selection and get data you need ._.
i think you got `HTML Collection` because of you extracting dom element object from each span

Comment: @WellNo I updated the question

Comment: @WellNo as David Thomas  mentioned little more code would be useful, how html looks like inside the `spans`?

Comment: okay I will add it to my question, just a seccond !

Comment: updated it with more background information !

Comment: your code works but also gives me something weird bag. The exact output needs to be : 20,15,10,5,1 - but it gives me: 20,15,10,5,1 - so 2 times the same output in a single alert